# What separates a subspace from the entire vector space it is a subspace of?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

This is more of a philosophical question about what differs the definitions of a vector space and a subspace.

In looking at subspaces of a vector space $V$, we have one such approach through linear combinations where given $v_1+v_2+...+v_n$ of this vector space, we have a set of coefficients $x_1+x_2+...+x_n$ that satisfy this vector space.

One example that comes to mind is the set of continuous functions $y=f(x)$ that sum to fill $\Bbb R^2$. For such a vector space, if all arbitrary continuous functions fill all of the values of the vector space, then why is this not the entire vector space itself?

One such argument that defines the linear combination as a subspace is that we could take another set of coefficients $y_1+y_2+...+y_n$ and similarly add it to the first set of coefficients and then multiply it into our subspace to show that we end up with $(x_1+y_1)v_1+(x_2+y_2)v_2+...+(x_n+y_n)v_n$, and thus, this shift to the entire set shows that either $X^\prime V$ or $Y^\prime V$, or $(X+Y)^\prime V$ are all subspaces.

However, isn't it true that any vector space $V$ is itself defined by a set of all possible vectors, and if so, then couldn't this set be similarly multiplied by different sets of coefficients to define them as a subspace of $V$ as opposed to the entire constitution of $V$? If this is the case, then it suggests there is no vector space $V$, and there is no such thing as a vector space, but instead just an infinite number of subspaces that are all to some degree subspaces or "superspaces"(?) of each other.

Once you define a vector space, then there seems to be nothing that fully defines the vector space except an arbitrary label of the space. Once labeled (i.e., "vector space $V$"), given the sudden infinite number of approaches to vectors in this space, then besides the specific words "Vector Space $V$," any definition that fits the space is just a subspace.

Comment: You might ask the question, “Suppose I have a vector space V.  Is there a subset of V that is also a vector space?”  That is a vector subspace.

Answer (score 0):

A subspace of a vector space is a vector space in it's own right. What makes them different is when the subspace has a lower dimension than the vector space that it originates.

A vector space merely satisfies certain axioms, being:

- Associativity of addition
- Commutativity of addition
- Identity of addition and scalar multiplication
- Inverse of addition
- Distributivity of scalar multiplication over vector and field addition.
- Compatibility of scalar multiplication with field multiplication

The majority of these are absorbed as a subspace. A subspace merely needs to worry about it's elements containing the additive inverse and additive and scalar multiplicative closure.

---

I don't fully follow your talk above, but it sounds like your concern is to do with the underlying basis of a vector space. If you are saying that there are a multitude of choices for your basis vectors, you are correct.

Comment: Fair enough, but doesnt that mean that once you claim a definition to any vector space, then there will inherently be no way to absolutely define it, and any effort to do so will only yield subspaces?

Comment: @Topher Are you familiar with a basis of a vector space?

Comment: Not specifically, but in a quick glance at the topic, I can see that that seems to be where my book is getting to. :) It doesn't have a specific section on Basis though.

Comment: @Topher When you learn span, you may wonder what a minimal number of vectors that span the space is, e.g. all of your spanning vectors are linearly independent, here you will have shown a basis(where the number of linearly independent vectors that span your whole space, is the dimension of the space). You will then find that you have many choices for your basis. E.g. numerous choices of vectors span your vector space.

Comment: Sweet! Thanks for the tips. Looking forward to it. :)